# persistence.xml transaction-type="JTA"

Tags: java, xml, persistence, openjpa, jta

Is this `perisistence.xml` file correct, especially when i  `transaction-type="JTA"` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CollDocPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<class>model.entity.StudentAddSolution</class>
<class>model.entity.Lecturer</class>
<class>model.entity.Solution</class>
<class>model.entity.Student</class>
<class>model.entity.Course</class>
<class>model.entity.File</class>
<class>model.entity.CourseHasLecturer</class>
<class>model.entity.Mail</class>
<class>model.entity.StudentAtCourse</class>
<class>model.entity.Roles</class>
<class>model.entity.Task</class>
<class>model.entity.User</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:11080/myBase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass,"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myBase"/>
  <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you getting an error?

If you are using JTA I will suggest you use a DataSource as a provider of your connections.

Such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CollDocPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<jta-data-source>datasource</jta-data-source> 
<class>model.entity.StudentAddSolution</class>
<class>model.entity.Lecturer</class>
<class>model.entity.Solution</class>
<class>model.entity.Student</class>
<class>model.entity.Course</class>
<class>model.entity.File</class>
<class>model.entity.CourseHasLecturer</class>
<class>model.entity.Mail</class>
<class>model.entity.StudentAtCourse</class>
<class>model.entity.Roles</class>
<class>model.entity.Task</class>
<class>model.entity.User</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

BTW, you need to close all yours tags

Regards

Comment: how can i use DataSource as a provider of my connections ? i'm sorry but i'm new and don't understend everything

Comment: In the way you were working, I think you would use RESOURCE_LOCA as transaction-type

Comment: but when i use "RESOURCE_LOCA" i have error: ` java.lang.NullPointerException
at model.beans.UserFacade.findByLogin(UserFacade.java:34)` and when i use `JTA` i have error: `Caused by:
org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException - type not found or user lacks privilege: TEXT {stmnt 1013050998 CREATE TABLE COURSE (id_course SMALLINT NOT NULL, code VARCHAR(255), description TEXT, name VARCHAR(255), realization INTEGER, version SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (id_course)) ENGINE = innodb} [code=-5509, state=42509]
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecora`

Comment: i get EnitityManager by @EJB annotation i managed Bean in my application

Comment: How can you get an EntityManager by @EJB annotation? If you are using EM in an EJB you would use PersistenceContext to retrieve an entityManager

Comment: i'm sorry, you are right. I get EM by `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "CollDocPU")`

Comment: Removing `openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings` didn't help

Comment: After remote, get the entityManaget by this way: EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CollDocPU");
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Comment: As I told you, before doing this: EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("CollDocPU"); EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); Just print the em by System.out and tell me what you get

Answer (score 0):

My friend, Maybe that is another error, try this, after doing what I told you, just print the EntityManager by System.out.println(em.toString()); If you are getting something, It is because It is OK, the nullpointer that you are getting in the other method could be by the program logic

Comment: EntityManager object reference is null, so when i have`em.createNamedQuery("User.findByLogin").setParameter("login", login);` i get nullPointerExecption

Comment: Using RESOURCE_LOCAL and deleting SynchronizeMappings?

Comment: Trying what I told you, remove also the provider tag, It must take the default provider of the enviroment